# How to delete a empty list from a column in PySpark?

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a df like the next one (the df have a lot more columns and rows than shown):

```
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|               00021|               00064|               00092|
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|[10.0, 93.0, 499....|                  []|                  []|
|                  []|[613.138964292777...|                  []|
|                  []|                  []|[307.761967200347...|
|                  []|                  []|                  []|
|                  []|                  []|                  []|
|                  []|                  []|                  []|
|                  []|                  []|                  []|
|                  []|                  []|                  []|
|                  []|                  []|                  []|
|                  []|                  []|                  []|
|                  []|                  []|                  []|
|                  []|                  []|                  []|
|                  []|                  []|                  []|
|                  []|                  []|                  []|
|                  []|                  []|                  []|
|                  []|                  []|                  []|
|                  []|                  []|                  []|
|                  []|                  []|                  []|
|                  []|                  []|                  []|
|                  []|                  []|                  []|
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

And i like to delete all the rows with empty lists on them and then make an explode to get the next one df:

```
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|               00021|               00064|               00092|
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|         10         |                null|                null|
|         93         |                null|                null|
|        499         |                null|                null|
|                null| 613.1389642927775  |                null|
|                null|        146         |                null|
|                null| 47.867710185002025 |                null|
|                null|                null| 307.7619672003473  |
|                null|                null|        347         |
|                null|                null| 889.7293449318846  |
|                null|                null|                null|
|                null|                null|                null|
|                null|                null|                null|
|                null|                null|                null|
|                null|                null|                null|
|                null|                null|                null|
|                null|                null|                null|
|                null|                null|                null|
|                null|                null|                null|
|                null|                null|                null|
|                null|                null|                null|
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

I'm able to doit just to one column using:

```
newPivot0 = pivotTest.select('00021').filter(Functions.size('00021') > 0)
newPivot = newPivot0.select(Functions.explode('00021').alias('00021'))
newPivot.show()
```

To get:

```
+--------------------+
|               00021|
+--------------------+
|                10.0|
|                93.0|
|               499.0|
|               474.0|
|               248.0|
|   677.7762094355725|
|               558.0|
|0.021107340682280373|
|  294.55873173592926|
|  132.00825488704737|
|               308.0|
|               347.0|
|   285.1770132879582|
|               332.0|
|               332.0|
+--------------------+
```

So... how can I apply the same operation to all columns in the df?

I'm using GCP Dataproc to test this code, in spark v3.1.2 and python 3.

Comment: Do include the expected output when operation is applied to all columns?

Answer (score 0):

If you can use pandas, the function dropna remove missing values. And put the parameter how='all' to indicate when you want to remove rows from dataframe when all values are NA.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[10,None,None],[None,None,None],[None,146,None],[None,None,307.7],[None,None,None]],
                  columns=['00021','00064','00092'])
df.dropna(how='all')
df
```

Input:

[image: input]

Output:

[image: output]

Comment: I'm tring no to use pandas but if I cant find an easier way on spark I'll use Pandas. The key here are the empty lists. The original df dont have 'NaN' or 'Null' values, it have '[ ]' ( empty lists ) values.